# Remote logging to specific directory structure with rsyslog

Tags: debian, logging, rsyslog

I'm currently in the process of having all of our various servers send their syslog messages to a central server.  I'd like to have the following directory structure on the central server that logs are sent to.

```
<root_dir>/<server_name>/<year>/<month>/<day>/{messages, mail, auth, etc}.log
```

Is this something I can do with rsyslog templates alone or do I need to use another utility to move the files into the proper file location?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about creating the directories, but the rest should be handled by filters and dynamic file names.

Normally in a case like this I would log file pattern like.

```
/var/log/<server_name>{messages,mail,auth,etc}.YYYYMMDD
```

Having the logs separated by server may make tracing conditions across servers difficult.  The log messages typically include the originating server, so it is easy to retrieve messages for a particular server with `awk`, `grep` or any other pattern matching tool.  Scaling out that many log files may also be difficult, and you may hit resource limits.

Typically log rotation is handled by a program like `logrotate`.  This allows you to control the frequency of log rotations for particular files, and to control the number of versions you keep.  It's `postrotate` action could be used to split out date from the just rotated files into the desired form.  This may scale better.